# uninitialized constant SessionsController - Routing error + Devise + Ruby on Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise

I have overwritten sessions controller and registrations controller of
devise and have given custom paths. I have been doing this in past few
projects and it was working fine, I don't know why I am getting this
error now.

Here are the routes :-

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:sessions =>
"sessions", :passwords => "passwords", :registrations =>
"registrations"} do
   get "signup", :to => "registrations#new"
   get "login", :to => "sessions#new"
   post "login", :to => "sessions#new"
   get "logout", :to => "devise/sessions#destroy"
 end
```

These routes have worked before, can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a really stupid mistake on my part, I misspelled sessions_controller while overriding sessions_controller.

Answer (score 2):

Can also be caused by incorrect file name of session_controller.rb